# terminal opens with ".zprofile:6: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew"

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, apple-silicon

After downloading brew from this command

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

I am running these two commands

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/alibaig/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

I am getting this

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

Output of cat ~/.zprofile

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Comment: Can you give the return of `cat .zprofile`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it seems like you may be running the installation from some other account on your device, like it was in my case.

If that is so, then running the line

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

would lead to the installation of brew to some other folder.

**What to do?**

When running the installation, before the acceptance of installing (requirement to press Enter), observe the first line proposed, for me it was

```
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

If that is so, you should modify the second line you execute to:

```
eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was the answer for me, thank you sir! Default was the same for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)? To do so, open the Terminal and paste in the command that is provided on the Homebrew website.

Homebrew is a package manager for Mac, and apparently something in your `~/.zprofile` file is invoking it. This file contains some configuration for your shell.

If you already have Homebrew and this does not solve it, please update your question with the output of the following command: `cat ~/.zprofile`. Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, if you don't have or know what Homebrew is, you can open up `.zprofile` and remove any lines that reference it.

Comment: Why is this an answer?  The only reason zprofile would be referencing Homebrew would be if the OP *put it there* in the first place.

Comment: @MarcWilson My assumption was he installed something (ran a script) that edited his .zprofile, otherwise he would not have asked the question.

Comment: I'm having the issue as the OP but for me, I had installed Homebrew, found I didn't really use it, then ran the removal script from the Homebrew site. So it seems like some residual things are left and not purged, leaving ever terminal opening with the same line as OP. Any advice on how I might remove it? Thank you.

Comment: @colorful-shirts If you have similar errors as the OP, you will get a file location and an error line number where those errors occur (e.g. for OP it was in ~/.zprofile at lines 6 and 7). Use these clues to find out where the residual things are still being called and update those scripts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `PATH` for Python 3.8 - The original version is saved in `.zprofile.pysave`

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Setting `PATH` for Python 3.9 - The original version is saved in `.zprofile.pysave`

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

This is my output of `cat ~/.zprofile`.